# jquery doesn't work to set background-image

Tags: jquery

I have this html code

```
<div class="gallery-item"><img src="images/thumbnails/img_(1).jpg" /></div>
```

this css code

```
.gallery-item
{
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
margin: 10px 12px;

overflow: hidden;

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;

cursor: pointer;
}
```

and this Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".gallery-item").each(function(index, element) {
     var img = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
     $(this).css("background-image", "url("+img+")");
     $(this).children("img").remove();
  });
});
```

but it doesn't work. just delete img tag and leave .gallery-item without any background!
but when i try this code it works:

```
$(this).css("background-image", "url()");
```

and just set my index page address to background-image.

also i tried to set background-color and it worked!

help me out

Comment: Try `backgroundImage`.

Comment: Add `console.log(img)` after the line where you assign the value to this variable to  see if it actually contains what you expect.

Comment: @putvande it doesn't work too!

Comment: @CBroe: I tried alert(img) and everything was fine! but still didn't work!

Comment: try this `$(this).css("background-image", "url('../" + img + "')");`

Comment: ur code is working fine [demo](http://jsbin.com/uMiSUZA/3/edit)... so check with your image source

Comment: @AmitSoni: no work!
my DOM didn't change after executing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(this).css("background-image", 'url("'+img+'")');
```

Comment: background-image value is in this format "url(address)" but src value is just a pure address!
i tested it! it doesn't work too :(